# Simple click alternative to Draggable views?

Tags: ajax, views

I'm trying to find an alternative solution to the [Draggable views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module. But instead of **dragging** the rows, you just **click** some simple **up and down arrows** once, and you click any of them to reorder them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The standard ordering for lists of nodes or entities in Drupal is first by the "sticky" attribute and then by the created date. Many content modules have some facility to change this ordering, but only for their content type. The modules described in the Community documentation about [Comparison of node ordering modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/398508) attempt to provide a more controllable ordering in a variety of ways.

Here is the list of modules mentioned in that documentation (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Outline Designer](https://www.drupal.org/project/outline_designer):

  > ... is a user experience module that makes book management more intuitive. Essentially it overlays on the admin book outline page so that you can use AJAX to build and edit site outlines much faster then Drupal traditionally allows.
- [Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight):

  > ... adds a weight option to enabled node types. Nodes with lower weight will float to the top of lists, while heavier items will sink.
- [Nodeorder](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeorder):

  > ... gives users an easy way to order nodes within their taxonomy terms.
  >
  > By default, the taxonomy module orders listings of nodes by stickiness and then by node creation date -- most recently posted nodes come first.
  >
  > The nodeorder module gives the user the ability to manually put nodes in any order they wish within each category that the node lives.
- [Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue):

  > ... allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose, such as:
  >
  > - A block listing teasers for the five top news stories on a site
  > - A user’s favorite music albums
  > - A group of favorite from which one is randomly displayed
- [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews):

  > Have you ever rearranged Blocks?, sorted Taxonomy terms? or reordered Menu items at the Drupal administration pages? All these pages use the tabledrag.js javascript that enables Drag'n Drop on HTML-tables.
  >
  > With DraggableViews you can apply this tabledrag.js to any Views-generated table.
- [Flag Weights](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_weights):

  > ... very simple module that adds a 'weight' field to the tables already used by the excellent [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.
  >
  > This weight can then be used to provide ordering of flagged items. This module also provides a Views field which can be used to sort flagged items. One interesting use of this ability is to integrate with [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) to create a user-sortable list of flagged items.
- [Sortable Grid Views Plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/sgrid):

  > ... provides a Views plugin for the user to be able to show a grid composed of draggable elements and save the displayed order of these element.
  >
  > The user may then create other displays to show the elements in the order defined above.
  >
  > This project is very similar in its goals to [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews), yet a lot simpler as there is no hierarchy management. It doesn't depend on [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) though.
  >
  > The added value resides in the presentation, a grid rather than a table list, and the therefore possible uses which [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) doesn't permit.
- [JQGRID - View integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqgrid):

  > ... provides views integration for the jqGRid jQuery plugin, which
  >   provides advanced interaction controls to HTML tables such as dynamic
  >   pagination, on-the-fly filtering, and column sorting.
  >
  > For full documentation and examples, visit the [jqGRid jQuery plugin page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)
- [Nodeflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeflow):

  > ... gives a drag and drop interface for publishing nodes and positioning them in your desired order. This is useful for large publishing sites where editors can get a bird's eye view of all nodes currently on the frontpage and all nodes waiting to be published. A drag and drop interface helps to publish nodes quickly into desired positions.
- [Queues](https://www.drupal.org/project/queues):

  > - Adds new Queues entity
  > - Revisionable
  > - Support multiple Bundles
  > - Support reference to any Entity/Bundle
  > - Full State Machine Support (Queues Workbench)
  > - Supports Revision Scheduler Module (Queues Workbench)
  > - Revision Revert Operation
  > - Revision Delete Operation
  > - Revision Publish Operation (Queues Workbenc integration)
  > - Revision Unpublish Operation (Queues Workbenc integration)